How to add a counter next to each href link of video in php page
I am weak in Ajax. I searched a lot for examples that would help me solve my problem, but I did not find any. I have a list of videos on a php page, and I want to add a counter next to each link. I tried to use Ajax, but I do not know how to restore the counter of this video to the main page. I would be grateful if I find someone to help me.
home.php Home page contains a list of links to play videos
I want to send id of vedio onclick href link using ajax to addClick.php page to update the counter element and retrieve the new one.
I want to send animation id  to the ajax script to send it to the addClick.php i dont know what is the wrong in ajax or if i pass the id true to the function
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "vc";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<div id="anim">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM counter";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 
  echo "<a href=".$row['link']." target='_blank' onclick='addClick(".$row['id'].")'>".$row['name']."</a><div id='res'>".$row['counte']."</div><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?> 
</div>

<script>
function addClick(id) {
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("anim").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","addClick.php?id="id,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

addClick.php
 
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "vc";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "UPDATE counter SET counte=counte+1 WHERE id=?";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?> 


Don't you have a console error in the browser? "addClick.php?id="id should be "addClick.php?id="+id - you forgot the concatenation operator

Also your addClick.php script never even tries to use the ID anyway

i got this error ,  Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Yes, because you wrote a paramterised query but didn't actually prepare it, or add any parameters. Look at the examples here of how it's supposed to work.

Bear in mind you'll also need to actually retrieve the id from $_GET["id"] as well

Thanks everyone its worked
